# Commutation relation for general case $[a^n, \bar{a}^m]=?$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I want to find some formula related with 
\begin{align}
[a^n, \bar{a}^m]=?
\end{align}
with $[a,\bar{a}]=d$ for some constant number $d$.

Note here $[A,B]= AB-BA$. $i.e$, $[ , ]$ is usual commutator.

First after some computation i obtain 
\begin{align}
&[a,\bar{a}^m] = m \bar{a}^{m-1} [ a ,\bar{a}] \\
& [ a^n, \bar{a}] = n a^{n-1} [ a,\bar{a}]
\end{align}
By applying some formula like $BAC-CAB$ rule.

I want to obtain some formula related with $[a^n, \bar{a}^m]$, but it seems my formula dosen't seem nice,

Do you have any idea or guess for the form of $[a^n, \bar{a}^m]=$?

---

Consider the case for 
\begin{align}
[a^2, \bar{a}^2] &= [a,\bar{a}^2]a + a[a,\bar{a}^2]  \\
&=  ([a,\bar{a}]\bar{a} + \bar{a}[a,\bar{a}])a + a( [a,\bar{a}]\bar{a} + \bar{a}[a,\bar{a}]) \\
& = [a,\bar{a}]2(\bar{a}a+a\bar{a}) = [a,\bar{a}] 2( [a,\bar{a}] +2\bar{a}a) = 2 [a,\bar{a}]^2 + 4 [a,\bar{a}] \bar{a}a 
\end{align}

Comment: I am not saying move it there, but did you search MathSE? And just because conventions differ, the upper  bar is complex conjugate?  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45053/2451

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly nicer way of thinking about it. The relation $[a, \bar{a}] = d$ can be rephrased as saying, "you can move a $\bar{a}$ to the left of an $a$, but you pick up an extra $d$ term".

Now, we want to compute the difference of $a^n \bar{a}^m$ and $\bar{a}^m a^n$. To convert the former into the latter, we need to move a $\bar{a}$ past an $a$, $nm$ times (that is, $n$ times for each of the $m$ $\bar{a}$'s), picking up a factor of $d a^{n-1} \bar{a}^{m-1}$ every time. Then the answer is
$$[a^n, \bar{a}^m] = mnd a^{n-1} \bar{a}^{m-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use these relations
$$\begin{align}[a,bc] &=[a,b]c+b[a,c]\\  [ab,c] &=a[b,c]+[a,c]b\\ [a,\bar{a}^m] &=[a,\bar{a}]\bar{a}^{m-1}+\bar{a}\left[a, \bar{a}^{m-1}\right]\end{align}$$

This is a recursive relationship
$$=d\bar{a}^{m-1}+\bar{a}\left(d\bar{a}^{m-2}+\bar{a}\left[a, \bar{a}^{m-2}\right]\right)$$

And so on.. after $m$ recursions

$$=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \left(\bar{a}^{m-1}d\right)=m\bar{a}^{m-1}d$$

Similarly 
$$[a^n,\bar{a}]=na^{n-1}d$$

Now consider 
$$\begin{align}[a^n, \bar{a}^{m}] &=a^{n-1}\left[a,\bar{a}^{m}\right]+\left[a^{n-1}, \bar{a}^m\right]a\\ &=a^{n-1}m\bar{a}^{m-1}d+\left[a^{n-1}, \bar{a}^m\right]a\end{align}$$

After $n$ recursions
$$\begin{align} &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}mda^{n-1}\bar{a}^{m-1}\\ &=mnda^{n-1}\bar{a}^{m-1}\,.\end{align}$$

Comment: Actually the first thing i guess was exactly same as your idea. But i got confused by computing a^2 bar a^2 case. At this case i obtain 2(a bar a + bar a a)d. And apparently this is not same as 4a bar a d since a bar a is not the same as bar a a