# Commutator calculation - tips?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I have to find out the following commutator 
$$
[a^\dagger a^\dagger a, a^\dagger a a]
$$ 
and after expanding it with $[A,B]=AB-BA$
$$
[a^\dagger a^\dagger a, a^\dagger a a] = a^\dagger a^\dagger a a^\dagger a a - a^\dagger a a a^\dagger a^\dagger a
$$
I begun to wonder - is there some kind of easier method to calculate such expressions or I just have to use the relation 
$ [a, a^\dagger] = a a^\dagger - a^\dagger a = 1$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45053/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by using the fact that $[a,a] = [a^{\dagger},a^{\dagger}] = 0$ together with $[A,BC]=B[A,C]+[A,B]C$ and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
[a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} a, a^{\dagger} a a] &=& a^{\dagger}[a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} a,  a a]+[a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} a, a^{\dagger} ]a a \\
&=& a^{\dagger}[a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger},  a a]a + a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} [ a, a^{\dagger} ]a a \\
&=& a^{\dagger}[a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger},  a a]a + a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} a a \ .
\end{eqnarray}
Now what remains is simpler.