# Commutators in second Quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

How do you calculate the commutator
$$[b_i^n, (b_j^\dagger)^m]$$
where $b_i$ are annihilators and $b_j^\dagger$ are creators in second quantization. All annihalators should be swapped to the right side.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45053/2451

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The cleverest way to calculate $\left[\hat{a}^{M},\hat{a}^{\dagger N}\right]$ with $\left[\hat{a},\hat{a}^{\dagger}\right]=1$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45053/)

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the definition of the commutator
$$[A B, C] = A B C - C A B = ABC - ACB + ACB - CAB \\= A (BC - CB) + (AC - CA)B = A[B, C] + [A,C]B$$
which generalizes to
$$ [A^n, B] = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} A^m[A,B]A^{n-m-1}$$
by repeated application. You should be able to do the rest yourself from here.

Comment: There's a problem here, since your formula with $n=1$ implies that $[A,B]=[A,B]A+A[A,B]$. I think it's that the upper bound should be $n-1$.