# Writing normally ordered operator $a^{\dagger n}a^m$ in terms of anti-normal order

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics

I am looking for a formula to write a normally ordered operator ${a}^{\dagger n} a^m$ as a function of  anti-normally ordered operators $a^i {a}^{\dagger j}$. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, you know how to work out the commutator of $a^{\dagger n}$ with $a^m$, and thence... you want a compact expression? Are you aware of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0385)?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45053/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are far too many expressions around to know which one you'd find the most useful. It may be that your starting expression is just a generic term in an expansion of something easier, in which case you'd end up reduplicating steps.

The standard generic technique is relying on generating functions:
$$
a^{\dagger ~ n } a^m=\left. \partial_\sigma ^n \partial_\tau ^m \left ( e^{\sigma a^\dagger}  e^{\tau a}\right ) ~~  \right|_{\sigma=\tau=0} .
$$
But you know from the lowest order [(degenerate) CBH identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Application_in_quantum_mechanics) that 
$$
e^{\sigma a^\dagger}  e^{\tau a} =    e^{\sigma \tau [a^\dagger, a]}  e^{\tau a}  e^{\sigma a^\dagger} =  e^{-\sigma \tau }  e^{\tau a}  e^{\sigma a^\dagger} , 
$$
so that your original expression is anti normal ordered by 
$$
a^{\dagger ~ n } a^m= \left.\partial_\sigma ^n \partial_\tau ^m \left ( e^{-\sigma \tau  }  e^{\tau a}  e^{\sigma a^\dagger}  \right ) ~~ \right|_{\sigma=\tau=0} .
$$

- Confirm to your satisfaction how this works for, e.g., *n*=1, *m*=3, $$ 
   \left.\partial_\sigma  \partial_\tau ^3 \left ( e^{-\sigma \tau  }  e^{\tau a}  e^{\sigma a^\dagger}  \right ) ~~ \right|_{\sigma=\tau=0} = \left.  \partial_\tau ^3 \left (    e^{\tau a}   ( a^\dagger-\tau)  \right ) ~~ \right|_{\tau=0}= a^3 a^\dagger -3a^2.$$ This *never* involves expanding exponentials, as you fear--merely the eigenfunction property of exponentials  w.r.t. derivation.

For an arbitrary normally ordered operator, substitute $a^\dagger \mapsto \partial_\sigma, \quad a \mapsto \partial_\tau$, and repeat the maneuver. Experiment with simple functions, not mere monomials, to see how it works.