# Complicated bosonic commutations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

Given that $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are bosonic annihilation and creation operators (in the language of second quantisation); are there any simpler ways to calculate the commutators of arbitrary products of these operators, without laboriously using the key bosonic identity $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ over and over again. For example, given the commutator

$$[a^\dagger a a^\dagger a^\dagger, a^\dagger a a^\dagger a],$$

are there any handy tricks for just reading off the result, or making the computations quick?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45053/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This is the 170,000th question asked on the site! Woohoo!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are exactly 137 tricks and 29.5 relevant questions on this site, and the linked questions to them.

For "mixed" expressions like yours, the very *first* thing you do is isolate the number operators $N=a^\dagger a$, for which
$$
[N,a^{\dagger ~n}]=n a^{\dagger ~n}, \qquad [N,a^{n}]=-n a^{ n}, 
$$
with *N* commuting with itself, of course.

So you reduce your expression to commutators of powers of creators with powers of annihilators, for which @Qmechanic 's link steers you to elegant expressions.

For example, your expression is
$$
[N a^{\dagger ~ 2}, N^2]= N\{ [a^{\dagger ~ 2},N],N\}= 4N(1-N)a^{\dagger ~ 2},
$$
etc. You should be able to  hack many of them by inspection.

Also take a look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/417672/66086).